# Abstract Wave with Particle System

Tags: particles

I want to create a wave made out of particles/dots. The wave should look like this:

[image]

I tried to achieve this effect by adding an ocean modifier to a plane. Then I added a particle system to the plane but now I don't know how to go on. How can I make the particles lay on the 'ocean' and move when the ocean is moving?

PS: I know there is a way to do this with a material in the Blender Render. But firstly I want to create the whole thing in Cycles and secondly I want to have particles.

Comment: I was thinking of doing something similar and as a newbie to blender I'm curios if you continued working with a plane or any other kind of object for the particle system.

Comment: @John P Hey, Sorry but no, i didn't continue working on that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Method 1 - Dupliverts**

You should use a mesh such as a cube or a simple Icosphere for your particle, this will allow you to properly shade the particles like any other mesh

1. Select the particle mesh, in my case an Icosphere
2. Select the ocean
3. parent the particle to the ocean, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd>
4. Select the ocean
5. In mesh panel, set duplication type to verts

[image]

[image]

**Method 2 - Particle System**

1. Make sure your particle system is one the bottom of the modifier stack.

   [image]
2. In the particle system enable Use Modifier Stack

[image]

3. If you want to use another mesh as the particles you need to select the particle system and under the render tab, Select Object as your render type. Then you can choose you object.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but first of all this doesn't really work (I don't know why but what you said sounded logic for me) and second: I really want to use a particle system, because I want the particles to be keyed (physics of the particles)

Comment: OKay, I will update my answer

Comment: What do you do to add dupliverts after step 3? The menu lists 4 options