# Create a plasma-like effect in Blender

Tags: effects

I found this effect but don't know how it is called, but it reminds me of plasma (don't know why):

[image: A]
[image: B]
[image: C]

I'd like to apply this effect to a mesh to create something ghost-like. Something like this, but less opaque:
[image: cheesy unicorn]

How should I for a workflow to create something similar? Should I try modifying the final mesh? Or should I use particles or smoke simulation?

Comment: Please check the Duarte Farrajota Ramos' answer here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53032/how-do-you-use-blender-to-make-pokemon-attacks-like-hyper-beam-and-solar-beam The links he provided may be the solution for you.

Comment: I never try this, but it look like smoke simulation (high resolution with zero noise. and colored lights. Chceck this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWhuB_msmFg

Comment: and also check this: http://blenderdiplom.com/en/shop/611-point-density-magical-fx.html

Comment: @shubol3d you've added one link to French tutorial and second for commercial product...

Comment: @piegames do you need this effect for still image or animation?

Comment: @LukeD Yes I know where I point he, you don't need to remind me. Where is the problem? The both solve his problem. As first: French, Japan, Russian - what matter? How hard is understand from video what about going on? And as second: This is not my product, but point him to "point density" feature. Something wrong on this? He can buy or he can learn - now he knows what it is should focus. I wrote this only as tip, not as answer. Sometimes it looks here like at nursery school.

Comment: Thank you all for the links, they gave me an idea of how I could start doing this.
@LukeD It's for a still image

Comment: Reminds me of [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pau2HJsIF7U)

Answer (score -3):

### Don't use blender for this one

Since you only need a still image, there is no need for elaborate smoke simulations that take days to render.

If you really really wanted to use blender, try looking into [Abstract Wave with Particle System](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7434/abstract-wave-with-particle-system)

But really, it would be so much simpler, easier, and less time consuming to use something designed for creating art like this: http://www.escapemotions.com/products/flamepainter/

I even have made a demo of something similar to this that runs in realtime in JS to prove that you could code it yourself if you too. http://codepen.io/Thisisntme/full/KNpPEz/
[image]

If you wanted to know, my codepen works by creating a sequence of lines, and then dragging them down the screen (from left to right although it doesn't really matter) all while changing the y position with a few trig functions.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. It just says that it is difficult or perhaps (in your opinion) impossible.

Comment: @pycoder I did include a link to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7434/abstract-wave-with-particle-system, which has a similar effect.  It is an answer to the question. Saying that solutions are not feasible is indeed an answer.

Comment: Originally, my question wasn't really about hot to create this effect, but how to apply this effect to special forms, like an animal (or just a sphere to get started).