# How to achieve a dotted landscape

Tags: mesh

i try to achieve a dotted landscape like in this example.

[image]

I tried to solve it by an array but i dint get the landscape displacement to work.
an easy way would be to add a sphere to each point of a landscape mesh but i don't know how to do this.

Sorry if this is easy to solve, but i am kinda new to blender.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean dots like the material (green), or the lumpy ground?

Comment: i mean the glowing green spheres that are evenly distributed across the landscape

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28789 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7434 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48931

Answer (score 3):

You can do the texture using a brick texture node.

[image]

Then use a displacement modifier a highly subdivided plane.
For the displacement use a texture that as a height map for your landscape.

[image]

For more detail read:

[Landscape topography from grayscale image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27451/landscape-topography-from-grayscale-image/27454#27454)

For the glow use a glare node.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can create one segment with the shape of the light at it center:

[image]

Duplicate on X and Y with 2 *Array* modifiers, create mountains with a *Displace* modifier:

[image]

Give your light an *Emission* node, give the ground a dark green texture with a *Layer Weight* to make it glossy:

[image]

[image]

In *Eevee* play with the *Bloom* value to make the lights glow:

[image]